# Recording pulse audio as CAP_SYS_ADMIN with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, sudo, pulseaudio

As my normal user, this works:

```
ffmpeg -f pulse -i default -acodec aac foo.aac
```

but run with `sudo` is fails with:

```
default: No such process
```

How can I run ffmpeg as a privileged user (CAP_SYS_ADMIN), since I am keen to use the [kmsgrab option](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#kmsgrab) and still get access to sound in order to record it too?

Comment: This is probably best asked at unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps to connecting to the Pulse Audio server:

1. Server path. By default, the PulseAudio server makes itself accessible to clients by creating a UNIX socket under `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`. Running commands via `sudo` will reset the environment, thus making PulseAudio clients unable to find the server to connect to.
2. Authentication. By default, the PulseAudio server creates an authentication cookie in `~/.pulse-cookie`, which clients must relay to the server upon connecting. If `$HOME` or `$PULSE_COOKIE` are not set to the cookie's location, clients will be unable to authenticate.

The complete command of thus running ffmpeg via sudo is as follows:

```
sudo env \
    PULSE_COOKIE=$HOME/.pulse-cookie \
    PULSE_SERVER=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/pulse/native \
    ffmpeg -y -f pulse -i default -acodec aac foo.aac
```

You can probably substitute `PULSE_SERVER` with the `-server` ffmpeg [device option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#pulse).